# Set cookie expiry / max-age with localized time

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting a cookie server side and want to set the max-age attribute to 1800. It is my understanding that this will tell the browser to set the expiry time 1800 seconds from `Date.now()`.

The problem is, when I log `Date.now()` in my browser, it is not localized. So the time is showing 2:19pm when in actual fact it is 3:19pm due to it currently being daylight savings time.

So when my cookie is set, the expiry time is 30 minutes in the past.

It's probably not of any help but I have a function which sets my cookie like so:

```
setTokenCookie(token) {
    this.cookies.set("refresh_token", token.refresh_token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true })
    this.cookies.set("access_token", token.access_token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: token.expires_in })
  }
```

Is there a way to tell the cookie expiry to localize `Date.now()` before setting the expiry time?

Comment: What cookie library?

Comment: I am using Koa on my server. This has built in way of handling cookies and is working well. As you will see the cookie is `httpOnly` so I am not touching it on the frontend so am not using any FE cookie library

Comment: Then your server is one hour off?

Comment: Try using `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`

Comment: Yeah, you're right @mplungjan but server time and client time are unlikely to match up so wouldn't that always cause errors? Should the browser receive the max-age value and set expiry time according to it's own `Date.now()`?

Comment: Use `date.toUTCString()` when saving the value to the cookie...

Comment: @bastos.sergio & @Siemko sounds like you are saying to specify the expiry with the `expires` attribute. Since the time on the server and the time on the client are different, wont this cause issues? I.e. if server sets expire to 1pm but the client 12 hours ahead and has already passed that time then the cookie is immediately expired.

Comment: As mentioned in my original question, I was hoping to use `max-age` so the browser could see a value such as `1800` seconds and then set cookie expiration to (current localized time + 1800 seconds)

Comment: If you're using UTC, it won't matter if your browser is on one timezone, and the server is in another timezone. Also, if you wish to use max-age, that will also work.